# Implement user/usergroup level access to records in database (on application level)

Tags: sql

I have the following scenario:

1) a **Users** table:

```
int Id  (PK, Identity)
// more users table columns (firstname, etc.)
```

2) a **UserGroups** table:

```
int Id  (PK, Identity)    
// more usergroups table columns (title etc.)
```

3) a **UserGroupMembership** table:

```
int Id
int UserId  (FK->Users.Id)
int UserGroupId  (FK->UserGroups.Id)
```

and 4) a **Contacts** table:

```
int Id  (PK, Identity)
// more contacts table columns..
```

I'm looking for a way to have contacts in my **Contacts** table either "public" (everybody can see it), or restricted to any combination of one/multiple UserGroups or individual Users.

Completely stuck here.... Help?

Answer (score 1):

why not use an additional table relating Contacts and UserGroups?
e.g.

**ContactsAccess**

```
int UserGroups.Id (FK)
int Contacts.Id (FK)
```

You could use a special value (e.g. zero (0)) to indicate unrestricted access ,or you could modify the **Contacts** table to indicate the permission type.

Comment: It may also just be 4 individuals from "Users" and 2 groups. That would mean another relation table between Users and Contacts right?

That is going to be really expensive on data retrieval :(

Comment: if it requires Users as well, then I would say an additional table is the right choice.

Answer (score 0):

The way I'd probably go about it is a table similar to the following (MySQL):

```
CREATE TABLE `ContactsVisibleTo` (
    `ContactID` INT NOT NULL ,
    `Type` ENUM( 'User', 'Group' ) NOT NULL ,
    `ID` INT NOT NULL
)
```

A unique or primary key over all three fields probably isn't a bad idea either. The switch between public/private should be a field in the `Contacts` table.

Comment: joins to this table would still have to be doubled (on type='Contact'... and on type='Group') only it has the disadvantage of making the table itself larger. A two table approach has the same number of joins, but smaller tables, and the ability to use foreign key constraints.

Answer (score 0):

Here are two ways to do it without having to create additional M-N table for each entity in your db, as proposed in other answers:

1. You could add EntityBase table that all entities would inherit from (meaning there would be 1-1 relation on Entity id ).

   Hence, there would be only a single EntityAccess table with EntityId (fk) linking to EntityBase table. Contact table would have EntityId (fk,pk) column. You would query EntityBase table just when you would like.

   IIRC that's the approach used in VTiger CRM where there's a general CRMEntity table.
2. There's yet another way, used by MS Dynamics CRM. It prevents from adding intermediary tables for each entity, but doesn't ensure reference constraints.

The crux of this approach lies in the following table:

```
PrincipalObjectAccess
---------------------
...
PrincipalId
ObjectId
PrincipalTypeCode
ObjectTypeCode
AccessRightMask
...
```

PrincipalId may point to either UserId or TeamId (team is just a group of users). ObjectId may point to ANY entity in your model, depending on ObjectTypeCode (be it Contact, Account, Project etc).

AccessRightMask is a binary enumaration flag:

```
Read = 1
Write = 2
Append = 4
AppendTo = 16
Create = 16
Delete = 65536
Share = 262144
Assign = 524288
```